# A covering problem -- find $n$ triangles to cover $m$ points and minimize the total area of the $n$ triangles

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, linear-programming

Suppose we are given $m$ points on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider $n=1, 2, 3, \dotsc$; we want to cover the $m$ points with $n$ triangles (of any shape) while minimizing the total area of the $n$ triangles.

I first consider the case when $n=1$. We create a convex hull (a polygon) that contains all $m $ points. And by using linear algebra, we can use the line segments of the polygon to construct the desired triangle.

When $n=2$, of course we can make a similar attempt, but I have no idea if that's the intended way to do it. I feel like I'm missing some key observations or knowledge for solving this problem.

However, I would like to know how others think about this open problem. Any insights will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343892871_Covering_Points_by_Triangles) can help for $n=2$?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4596684/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156118/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).